# awk if nth column value multiples by X greater than Y

Tags: bash, awk

This is my file:

```
header 1 (which exists in my original file)
col1  col2 col3
name1 1K   1M
name2 2M   1K
name3 2K   2K
name4 2M   2M
name5 1K   5M
```

I want to do this:

> find the third column, if consists of M (megabytes) and (third column * 1024 ** 2 >= 2097152), then write the whole line to another file

Desired output (no matter if the first line (col1, col2, col3) exists in the output or not):

```
header 1 (which exists in my original file)
col1  col2 col3
name4 2M   2M
name5 1K   5M
```

These are my failed attempts (I even my attempts with syntax error):

```
tail -$(( $(wc -l the_file | awk {'print  $1'}) - 2 )) the_file | grep M | awk '$3 >= 2M'
tail -$(( $(wc -l the_file | awk {'print  $1'}) - 2 )) the_file | grep M | awk '$3 >= 2*1024**M'
tail -$(( $(wc -l the_file | awk {'print  $1'}) - 2 )) the_file | grep M | awk '$3+0 > 1M'
```

And then write the output to another file (the values should be kept in M)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `awk` should get the job done:

```bash
awk 'NR <= 2 || ($3 ~ /M$/ && $3+0 >= 2)' file

header 1 (which exists in my original file)
col1  col2 col3
name4 2M   2M
name5 1K   5M
```

We are printing those records where conditions are:

- `NR <= 2`: record number is 1 or 2
- `||`: OR
- `($3 ~ /M$/ && $3+0 >= 2)`: 3rd column ends with `M` and numeric value of 3rd column is greater than or equal to 2

Comment: Wow! How wonderful `awk` is, that does all thing in a single go instead of multiple commands and pipes:) thanks sir a lot

Comment: @Saeed given the content of your several recent questions and associated awk answers, you should get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn about awk.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the book, I'll purchase and study that for sure. I'm seeing `awk` very interesting for me as a sys admin to do the tasks and automate them.

Comment: @EdMorton it seems this book is free and I search the exact title, some websites have `awk` and others have `gawk`. Any differences between these two books? I googled and it seems `gawk` is the GNU version of `awk`.

Comment: The book isn't free. The author of the book is also the provider of gawk and sales of that book are the only income he gets from providing gawk and writing the documentation. He makes copies of it available online for reference for free, but everyone should buy a copy of the book to make sure he has an incentive to keep providing gawk and the documentation. Yes, gawk is the GNU version of awk, that book covers POSIX awk features as well as GNU awk extensions.

Answer (score 1):

> syntax error

In all your attempts

```
tail -$(( $(wc -l the_file | awk {'print  $1'}) - 2 )) the_file | grep M | awk '$3 >= 2M'
tail -$(( $(wc -l the_file | awk {'print  $1'}) - 2 )) the_file | grep M | awk '$3 >= 2*1024**M'
tail -$(( $(wc -l the_file | awk {'print  $1'}) - 2 )) the_file | grep M | awk '$3+0 > 1M'
```

you have put parts which are supposed to be part of `awk` program outside quotes, which are used for delimiting such program, if you want to print value of 1st column less 2 then you should write

```
awk '{print $1-2}' the_file
```

You do not need to know numbers of lines to use `tail` to start at n-th line, for example, if you need to start at 3rd line you might do

```
tail --lines=+3 the_file
```

You do not need `grep` there, as `awk` itself is able to filter, consider that in your case filtering with `M` is anywhere in line might be too lax, as it will allow not only lines with `M` in 3rd column, but also with `M` in other columns.

GNU `AWK` convert values between numeric and string when need to compare arise as described [Strings And Numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html), observe that it does not treat `2M` as 2097152, instead using longest prefix which is valid number, so if you want to support `K` as kilo- e.t.c. you need to implement that yourself.